# How to Call a payable function I am getting error={"code":-32603,"message":"Internal JSON-RPC error.","data":{"code":3,"message":"execution reverted"}

Tags: solidity, transactions, metamask, payable, etherjs

I am trying to call buy function which is a payable function using metamask signer method. I am getting error for sending incorrect ether value. Here I have set the price as 1 which is 0x01 in hex value.
Here is the solidity code for buy function:

```
        function buy(uint256 _tokenId) external payable {
        require(msg.value == 1, 'Incorrect value');
        _transfer(ownerOf(_tokenId), msg.sender, _tokenId);
        payable(ownerOf(_tokenId)).transfer(msg.value); // send the ETH to the seller
    }
```

Now I want to call this function using metamask. Here is the code:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
async function buyNFT()
{
    let params =[{
        from:"Address of the buyer",
        to: "Address of token owner",
        gas: '0x76c0',
        gasPrice: '0x9184e72a000',
        value:  '0x01',
        data: await contract.buy(0)
    }]
ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_sendTransaction', params,}).then((result) => {
      console.log("This is the result : ",result)
  }).catch((error) => {console.log("This is the error message:", error)});
```

But I am getting this error stating that-
**message: 'execution reverted: Incorrect value**

Answer (score 1):

when you call `await contract.buy(0)`, you are passing 0 as the param (which is _tokenId) and not the value.

The first thing it excecute is
`require(msg.value == 1, 'Incorrect value');`
msg.value here is not 1, so it reverts with this message.

to call the function with a value you need to use the overrides param:

```
 await contract.buy(0, {value: 1});
```